# Kinect- test data to simulate multiple tracked people

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm building a Kinect application in Unity (C#) that tracks multiple people. My stumbling block is how to test this without having several live 'actors' in front of the sensor.
I know Kinect Studio allows you to record live streams, but don't think this can be played back so that it feeds a Unity app. I am using the Kinect for Windows Unity package as a starting point.
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/kinect/tools

Any Kinect or Unity experts care to chime in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you **can** use recorded data to playback them without any "actors".

While you are running your app (and without the need of an actual Kinect device plugged in your PC), open Kinect Studio and chose *Open (Read-Only)* from *File*. Click then on the *Connect* icon under the *Play* tab:

[image: Kinect Studio]

After that, using the *Play* icon (the typical triangular-shaped one), your recordings will be send to the KinectService, so you can test your app without any actors.